# Why doesn't PackageInstallerActivity work with Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I used the following code to launch `PackageInstallerActivity`

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.packageinstaller", "com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity");

Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
newIntent.setComponent(comp);
```

But in Marshmallow, that's not working.

I found the answer, use `Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` instead of `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`.

But, why does `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` not work?

Answer (score 0):

Look this link [Android Document REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE), If your app is targeting API level higher than 25 you need to hold `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` in order to launch the application installer.